# Filtertering HTML tags

Tags: php, filter, html-entities

Is there any way to filter all html tags EXCEPT some tags of my choice like `<strong>, or <b>, <i>`? I know htmlentities would do the job but it will filter all of HTML tags.

Comment: there are lots of ways. can you be more specific about the context/language you want to do this in?

Comment: I am storing data using PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: http://www.php.net/strip_tags

```
// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

**Edit:** Actually, what you mean by "filter"?

Comment: I want to exclude all HTML tags EXCEPT <strong>, or <b>, <i>

Comment: Well, I think the above solution will do this job.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no safe way to do it. php's strip_tags will allow you those tags, but this means you will be vulnerable to xss. In order to avoid that, a better approach is kses (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/) is what wordpress uses.
Also, htmlpurifier (http://htmlpurifier.org/) is the way i would suggest to do it.

In your context, i would use strip_tags to keep only the tags i wanted, then i would pass the resulted string through htmlpurifier filter to be sure i won't get xss'ed.